# Numpy: running out of memory on one machine while accomplishing the same task on another

Tags: python, ubuntu, memory, numpy

For my project I need to store two large arrays in memory at once. I try to create them as follows:

```
matrix_for_words_train  = numpy.zeros(shape=(435679, 542))
matrix_for_words_test = numpy.zeros(shape=(435679, 542))
```

However, on my desktop pc the second string resulted in `MemoryError`.When I tried to perform this on my laptop, I succeeded. What puzzles me here is that desktop has twice as much memory as laptop (8 GB versus 4). Both machines run on Ubuntu, desktop has 12.04 while laptop has 14.04 (both 32-bit) and on both machines I tried to execute above script with python 2.7
Just in case I checked the memory available with `free` and it seems OK (total memory is shown as expected and desktop has more than twice free memory). I guess I'm totally missing something here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't confuse RAM with virtual memory.  Is the rest of the program and data identical?

Comment: Does the problem happen every time?

Comment: The amount of RAM involved is very close to the addressable virtual memory limit for a 32-bit OS without PAE enabled. I suspect that you are either (a) hitting this limit because your hardware/kernel don't support PAE or (b) your desktop has a graphics card that's sharing system memory and reducing the amount of RAM available to the system.

Comment: @otibom now that you ask, I remember that some time ago I stuck with similar issue, but that time it wasn't crucial. So the answer to your question is likely to be "yes".

Comment: @cdrake yes, they are the same

Comment: Try using the command- 'top' to view the memory and CPU usage. This will give you an idea about the memory used by the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both of the computers are 32 bits, they are practically both 4 GB RAM (unless you did weird things to solve it, like having PAE enabled).

32-bit operating system usually cannot handle more than 4 GB RAM.

Besides, Out of Memory exceptions are thrown by the operating system not only when there's practically no memory free memory at all for the entire system, but when it decides that's it can't allocate more memory for this particular process.

Further more, notice that arrays require a continues memory fragment. Thus, even if the OS can find enough free memory, it might not find this amount of free memory as one continues fragment. It's even possible there's not one continues fragment of 0.5 GB RAM in your entire system.

Do you have to use arrays? Can you implement your solution differently? If so, I would recommend that. What are you trying to do?

Anyway, Out of Memory exceptions are usually not so deterministic to eyes of the programmer. You might even won't get the same results on the same PC on the same day.